# Crear un servicio que no muera con la app

Tags: android

Hola estoy realizando una app para android y quería saber como crear un servicio que no muera al cerrar la app, que siga funcionando, ya que en el veo constantemente si tengo que mandar una notificación al usuario.

Answer (score 2):

Debes crear una clase que extienda de `service`:

```
public class miservicio extends service
{
   public miservicio() {
        super();
   }

   @Override
   public void Oncreate{

   }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

       //lo que quieras que haga tu servicio 
   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
   }

   @Nullable
   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return null;
   }

}
```

Y debes iniciarlo en el `MainActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, miservicio.class);
startService(intent);
```

Comment: Si se cierra la aplicación el servicio se detiene, y no es lo que desea el OP.

Answer (score 1):

Ve a la barra de herramientas de Android Studio y selecciona **File > New > Service > Service (Intent Service)**. Esto creará un nuevo `IntentService` basado en una plantilla prefabricada y lo agregará automáticamente al **AndroidManifest.xml**.

Los Intent Services aislan los procesos pesados en un hilo diferente del principal, para no entorpecer la UI si es que se encuentra activa.

A diferencia de `Service`, sus acciones van en el controlador `onHandleIntent()`:

```
public class WorkingIntentService extends IntentService {
    // TODO: Rename actions, choose action names that describe tasks that this
    // IntentService can perform, e.g. ACTION_FETCH_NEW_ITEMS
    public static final String ACTION_FOO = "com.herprogramacion.abtesting.action.FOO";
    public static final String ACTION_BAZ = "com.herprogramacion.abtesting.action.BAZ";

    // TODO: Rename parameters
    public static final String EXTRA_PARAM1 = "com.herprogramacion.abtesting.extra.PARAM1";
    public static final String EXTRA_PARAM2 = "com.herprogramacion.abtesting.extra.PARAM2";

    public WorkingIntentService() {
        super("WorkingIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_FOO.equals(action)) {
                final String param1 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PARAM1);
                final String param2 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PARAM2);
                handleActionFoo(param1, param2);
            } else if (ACTION_BAZ.equals(action)) {
                final String param1 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PARAM1);
                final String param2 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PARAM2);
                handleActionBaz(param1, param2);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle action Foo in the provided background thread with the provided
     * parameters.
     */
    private void handleActionFoo(String param1, String param2) {
        // TODO: Handle action Foo
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    /**
     * Handle action Baz in the provided background thread with the provided
     * parameters.
     */
    private void handleActionBaz(String param1, String param2) {
        // TODO: Handle action Baz
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

Como ves, puedes determinar que tipo de acción tomará el servicio con las acciones del Intent.

Y generar métodos `handleAction*()` para separar las elecciones.

Espero esto te sirve de ayuda.

Si quieres complementar te dejo esta guía: 
[Tutorial Para Crear Un Servicio En Android](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/07/tutorial-para-crear-un-servicio-en-android/)

Answer (score -1):

tenés que desarrollar la aplicación para que corra en background. Esto se hace usando el IntentService.

La clase IntentService proporciona una estructura sencilla para la ejecución de una operación en un solo hilo corriendo en segundo plano. Esto le permite manejar las operaciones de larga duración sin afectar a la capacidad de respuesta de la interfaz de usuario. Además, un IntentService no se ve afectada por la mayoría de los eventos de interfaz de usuario, por lo que continúa funcionando en circunstancias que cerraría una AsyncTask.

Para crear un componente IntentService para tu aplicación, tenés que definir una clase que se extiende IntentService, y dentro de ella, definir un método que anula onHandleIntent (). Por ejemplo:

```
public class RSSPullService extends IntentService {
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
        // Gets data from the incoming Intent
        String dataString = workIntent.getDataString();
        ...
        // Do work here, based on the contents of dataString
        ...
    }
}
```

**Definir el IntentService en el Manifest**
Un IntentService también necesita una entrada en su manifesto de aplicación. Proporcioná esta entrada como un elemento  que es un hijo del elemento :

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    ...
    <!--
        Because android:exported is set to "false",
        the service is only available to this app.
    -->
    <service
        android:name=".RSSPullService"
        android:exported="false"/>
    ...
<application/>
```

El atributo android: name especifica el nombre de la clase de la IntentService.

Observá que el elemento  no contiene un filtro de intención. La actividad que envía las solicitudes de trabajo para el servicio utiliza una intención explícita, por lo que no se necesita ningún filtro. Esto también significa que sólo los componentes de la misma aplicación o en otras aplicaciones con el mismo ID de usuario pueden acceder al servicio.

Ahora que tiene la clase básica IntentService, puede enviar solicitudes de trabajo a ella con objetos intención.

Podés fijarte en este link donde explican y enseñan a utilizarlo.

[Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)

Comment: Por lo general se recomienda ofrecer una respuesta muy detallada y mucho mejor si se ofrece un ejemplo y no un link, esto iría en un comentario.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio m0rg4n. Por favor brinda más detalle en la respuesta, porque en su estado actual parece más un comentario muy extenso. Los enlaces son para proveer información adicional. Sería bueno si provees al menos un ejemplo muy básico de cómo resolver este problema. La intención del sitio es que las respuestas sean auto contenidas y brinden lo necesario para resolver la pregunta.